# Cant figure out why this code is failing a single test

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to learn python more by solving the hacker rank puzzles and I can't understand why it is failing

This code is supposed to determine whether or not a year that is or above 1900 is, in fact, a leap year, the website says it passes 5 of 6 tests. For the input 
2100 it's returning true instead of false.

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    if year%4==0:
        return True
    elif year%100==0:
        return False
    elif year%400==0:
        return True


    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

I expect it to return false if the year is not divisible by 100 and return true if it is divisible by 4 or 400.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what happens if the year is, e.g. 1900, a year that was *not* a leap year:

Since `year % 4` is `0`, we return `True` immediately, which is of course wrong. In fact, *any* number that is divisible by 100 or 400 *must* also be divisible by 4, meaning that we never even get to the bottom two conditions.

So the solution is to reorder your conditions from most to least specific:

```
if year % 400 == 0:
    return True
elif year % 100 == 0:
    return False
elif year % 4 == 0:
    return True
```

Your second misunderstanding has to do with `return`: A `return` statement doesn't somehow "mark" a value to be the return value at the end of the function, it immediately exits the function, returning that value. For better consistency, I would remove the `leap` variable, and just `return False` at the end of the function. Alternatively, you could assign to `leap` inside the conditions instead of `return`ing there.

Answer (score -1):

Your if statement is not changing the variable `leap`.

Try changing the variable `leap` like below.

```
def is_leap(year):                                                                                                                                                          
    leap = False                                                                                                                                                            

    if year%4==0:                                                                                                                                                           
        leap = True                                                                                                                                                         
    elif year%100==0:                                                                                                                                                       
        leap = False                                                                                                                                                        
    elif year%400==0:                                                                                                                                                       
        leap = True                                                                                                                                                         


    return leap                                                                                                                                                             

year = int(input())                                                                                                                                                            
print(is_leap(year))
```

Comment: This will still not work, because the `elif`s will never be evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def foo(year: int) -> bool:
    "find a year is leapyear or not"
    if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
        return True
    return year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0
```

The function takes an integer as argument for the year parameter and returns `True` if the `year` is a leap year and `False` for the opposite. A year needs to be divisible by 4 and not by 100 to be a confirmed leap year. So, the conditional statement checks for that. If the condition's met it returns True else that function does not return anything and continues downward. Then, if the number is divisible by 4 and 100 and 400 as this case also means the year is a confirmed leap year, it returns True. We have done all checks and still if that's not True then certainly the years not a leap year.

Comment: The function takes an integer as argument for the `year` parameter and returns True if the year is a leap year and false for the opposite. A year needs to be divisible by 4 and not by 100 to be a confirmed leap year. So, the conditional statement checks for that. If the condition's met it returns True else that function does not return anything and continues downward. Then, if the number is divisible by 4 and 100 and 400 as this case also means the year is a confirmed leap year, it returns True. We have done all checks and still if that's not True then certainly the years not a leap year.

Comment: Don't tell it to me, edit your answer to explain what your code is doing and how it solves the problem at hand. You should especially focus on explaining what the problem with the original code is and how your code handles it.